# Testing Void Methods calling other Void Methods using NUnit and Moq

Tags: c#, testing, nunit

I am currently attempting to test the below code using NUnit and running into major problems as they are both void methods, one calling the other with the second calling another two methods. I was attempting to test the occurrences of the different methods being called but not sure if this is feasible which multiple void methods.

```
public class ApplicationResponseService : IApplicationResponseService
   {
       private readonly ITenantLookUpService _lookUpService;
       private readonly IConfigurationManagement _configurationManagement;
 
       public ApplicationResponseService(ITenantLookUpService lookUpService, IConfigurationManagement configurationManagement)
       {
           _lookUpService = lookUpService;
           _configurationManagement = configurationManagement;
       }

       public async void IterateTenants()
       {
           var allTenants = await _lookUpService.GetAllTenants();
           var connectionName =
               _configurationManagement.getConfig()[ConfigurationKeys.CONNECTION_LOOKUP_NAME];

                       foreach (var tenant in allTenants)
           {
               var tenantConnections = await _lookUpService.GetTenantDetails(tenant.OrganisationId);
               {tenantConnections.Connections.Count} connections for {tenant.OrganisationId}");
               processResponses(tenantConnections);
           }
       }

       public async void processResponses(TenantConnectionDetails tenantDetails)
       {
           var organisationId = tenantDetails.OrgId;
           var connection = _lookUpService.GetTenantConnectionDetails(tenantDetails.Connections, _configurationManagement.getConfig()[ConfigurationKeys.CONNECTION_LOOKUP_NAME]);
           var onlineConnection = _lookUpService.GetTenantConnectionDetails(tenantDetails.Connections, _configurationManagement.getConfig()[ConfigurationKeys.CONNECTION_NAME]);

          
           var responseToProcess = await collectResponses(organisationId, connection);

           foreach (var response in responseToProcess.LoanAppResponse)
           {
               var message = response.WholeTransferSuccessful ? formatSuccessResponse(response) : formatFailureResponse(response);

               message.OrganisationId = organisationId;
               message.ConnectionName = onlineConnection;

               EncryptAndSend(message, tenantDetails);
               deleteResponses(response, connection, organisationId);
           }
       }
```

I was attempting to go down the route of Mocking the class in general. Then calling the IterateTenants method and checking if ProcessTenants had any occurrences but unfortunately this was a dead-end.

Most recent attempt at testing if the IteractTenants method occurs is below:

```
[Test]
      public void testOverall()
      {
          var mock = new Mock<MortgageApplicationResponseService>();
          mock.Setup(x => x.IterateTenants());
          mock.Verify(x => x.IterateTenants(), Times.AtLeastOnce);
      }
```

Any insight or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify "attempting to test the occurrences of the different methods being called."  Also, which of the two methods are you asking about here test - I see both are public and would no doubt be tested separately. Also, may we assume that LookupService is tested separately?

Comment: Post an example of your test also please.  It will help us understand what you've tried.

Comment: Added my most recent attempt above. I'm hoping to test both methods (IterateTenants and ProcessTenants). Yes, LookUpService will be being tested separately